# Erase session traces in Windows

Tags: windows

Is there any inbuilt feature in Windows to completely erase all the session traces while 'Log off' or 'Shut down' ? I want my session traces like 'Recent files used', inputs of 'Run' dialog box etc. to be erased. Is this possible in Windows without installing any software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is not a built-in way of doing that - you have to do each one separately.

If you want **Run history** to be automatically deleted every time you start your computer, then go to the following location in the Registry Editor: HKEY_CURRENT_USER → Software → Microsoft → Windows → CurrentVersion → Policies → Explorer. There on the right hand side panel look for ClearRecentDocsOnExit, double click on it and type in its value as 1 and make sure Hexadecimal is selected. Then just click on OK and close the Registry Editor.

To turn **Recent Document** history off entirely, you'll also need to edit your registry:

1. Select Start -> Run -> and type
   "regedit"
2. Open folders in the registry to
   navigate to
   HCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\
   CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer
3. Set the data value for
   "NoRecentDocsHistory" to 1

But be warned that Windows keeps many logs of your activity, and that a computer professional specializing in this area can still unearth much information about your activities.